# When I try to get MIN value of manufactured parts I get (Only one expression ... when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS)

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, aggregate-functions

I try to get MIN value of manufactured parts grouped by project like so:

[image]

This is my query:

```
SELECT 
   proinfo.ProjectN 
  ,ProjShipp.[Parts] 
  ,ProjShipp.Qty AS 'Qty Total'
  ,Sum(DailyProduction.Quantity) AS 'Qty Manufactured'

  ,(SELECT  DailySumPoteau.IdProject, MIN(DailySumPoteau.DailySum) 
   FROM  (SELECT PShipp.IdProject,  SUM(DailyWelding.Quantity) DailySum  
          FROM   DailyWeldingPaintProduction DailyWelding 
          INNER JOIN ProjectShipping  PShipp ON PShipp.id=DailyWelding.FK_idPartShip  
          WHERE PShipp.id=ProjShipp.id 
          GROUP BY PShipp.id,PShipp.IdProject)DailySumPoteau  
    GROUP BY DailySumPoteau.IdProject ) AS 'Qt Pole'

 FROM [dbo].[DailyWeldingPaintProduction]  DailyProduction
 INNER join ProjectShipping ProjShipp on ProjShipp.id=DailyProduction.FK_idPartShip
 inner join ProjectInfo proinfo on proinfo.id=IdProject

  GROUP By proinfo.id
  ,proinfo.ProjectN 
  ,ProjShipp.[Parts] 
  ,ProjShipp.Qty
  ,ProjShipp.[Designation] 
  ,ProjShipp.id
```

I have three tables:

- 01 - `ProjectInfo`: it stores information about the project:

[image]

- 02 - `ProjectShipping`: it stores information about the parts and it has `ProjectInfoId` as foreign key:

[image]

- 03 - `DailyWeldingPaintProduction`: it stores information about daily production and it has `ProjectShippingId` as foreign key:

[image]

but when I run it I get this error:

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

How can I solve this problem?.

Comment: Please provide sample data for all three tables, along with the corresponding desired results. It is not easy to guess what you want just from the target result and a non-working query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your target results, I *suspect* that you want a window `MIN()`. *Assuming* that your query works and generates the correct results when the subquery is removed (column `QtPole` left apart), that would be:

```
SELECT pi.ProjectN, ps.[Parts], ps.Qty AS QtyTotal,
    SUM(dp.Quantity) AS QtyManufactured,
    MIN(SUM(dp.Quantity)) OVER(PARTITION BY pi.ProjectN) AS QtPole
    ps.Designation
FROM [dbo].[DailyWeldingPaintProduction]  dp
INNER join ProjectShipping ps on ps.id=dp.FK_idPartShip
INNER join ProjectInfo pi on pi.id=IdProject
GROUP BY pi.id, pi.ProjectN, ps.[Parts], ps.Qty, ps.Designation, ps.id
```

Side note: don't use single quotes for identifiers; they should be reserved for literal strings only. Use the proper quoting character for your database (in SQL Server: square brackets) - or better yet, use identifiers that do not require being quoted.

Answer (score 1):

Formulating the query in the way you have done is not necessarily the best solution. As [the other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65369689) mentions, the best method in this instance is probably to use a window function / `OVER`. But since this can depend on indexes, and also to understand what went wrong, I will give you the way to fix the original query.

The issue with your query is that it has a correlated subquery in the `SELECT` which returns two values. What you are trying to do can be done in RDBMSs that support row constructors, unfortunately SQl Server is not one of them.

What you are trying to get at here is to get a whole resultset per row of the table.
The correct syntax for your query is to `APPLY` the resultset of the subquery for every row. You can `CROSS APPLY` in this instance because you are guaranteed a result anyway due to the correlation:

```
SELECT 
   proinfo.ProjectN 
  ,ProjShipp.[Parts] 
  ,ProjShipp.Qty AS 'Qty Total'
  ,Sum(DailyProduction.Quantity) AS 'Qty Manufactured'
  ,QtPole.IdProject
  ,QtPole.MinDailySum

 FROM [dbo].[DailyWeldingPaintProduction]  DailyProduction
 INNER join ProjectShipping ProjShipp on ProjShipp.id=DailyProduction.FK_idPartShip
 inner join ProjectInfo proinfo on proinfo.id=ProjShipp.IdProject

 CROSS APPLY (
     SELECT  DailySumPoteau.IdProject, MIN(DailySumPoteau.DailySum) MinDailySum
       FROM  (SELECT DailyWelding.FK_idPartShip IdProject,  SUM(DailyWelding.Quantity) DailySum  
          FROM   DailyWeldingPaintProduction DailyWelding 
          WHERE DailyWelding.FK_idPartShip=ProjShipp.id 
          GROUP BY DailyWelding.FK_idPartShip) DailySumPoteau  
      GROUP BY DailySumPoteau.IdProject
  ) AS QtPole

  GROUP By proinfo.id
  ,proinfo.ProjectN 
  ,ProjShipp.[Parts] 
  ,ProjShipp.Qty
  ,ProjShipp.[Designation] 
  ,ProjShipp.id
  ,QtPole.IdProject
  ,QtPole.MinDailySum
```

I have taken the liberty of cleaning up the subquery by removing the unnecessary ProjectShipping reference. Note that the addition of grouping columns here does not matter because of the correlation to ProjShipp.Id

Note also that depending on indexes and density and such like, it may be better to formulate the subquery as a `JOIN` instead, with the correlation on the outside in the `ON`. You would need to modify the grouping in that case.